# $_GET values from link using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i did a setting page for my script ...
and in the form of the setting a did this

```
<form action='javascript:insert()'>
```

then i get all the values inserted on the input or checkbox or anything in the form of setting with javascript ..
just like:

```
function insert() {
// Optional: Show a waiting message in the layer with ID login_response
document.getElementById('huemix_message').innerHTML = "<img src='images/saver.gif' />"
// Required: verify that all fileds is not empty. Use encodeURI() to solve some issues about character encoding.
var system_name= encodeURI(document.getElementById('system_name').value);
var system_logo = encodeURI(document.getElementById('system_logo').value);
var system_number = encodeURI(document.getElementById('system_number').value);
var system_tel = encodeURI(document.getElementById('system_tel').value);
if($("#system_pics").is(':checked')){
      var system_pics = 1;
   } else {
      var system_pics = 0;
   }
if($("#system_bread").is(':checked')){
      var system_bread = 1;
   } else {
      var system_bread = 0;
   }

// Set te random number to add to URL request
nocache = Math.random();
// Pass the login variables like URL variable
http.open('get', 'huemixpanel_insert.php?system_name='+system_name+'&system_logo='+system_logo+'&system_number='+system_number+'&system_tel='+system_tel+'&system_pics='+system_pics+'&system_bread='+system_bread+'&uid='+uid+'&nocache = '+nocache);
http.onreadystatechange = insertReply;
http.send(null);
}
```

and every thing is working fine ..
i send all the values using ajax to another php page to update my database
now my quastion is :

in the same page i have a section to edit my members ..
i'm showing my members list using `" SELECT * FROM ..."`
result showing like this :

```
MEMBER    DEPARTMENT   ACCESS EDIT

admin        admin      all    edit
user2        service    service  edit
```

the "edit" word is a link like:

```
<a href='hueimx.php?action=edit&uid={$result['uid']}'>edit</a>
```

And `"{$result['uid']}"` This is a customer id getting from database

so the "edit" word of the admin user the link goes like this

```
<a href='huemix.php?action=edit?uid=1'>edit</a>
```

i want to send the generated [uid] from database to my javascript page

and get the uid value into a variable in ajax function to send it to another php file to update my database ,,, how to??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it as `href` add it to `onclick` in a js function -

```
<a href="#" onclick="edit_action({$result['uid']})">edit</a>
```

and create a function in js -

```
function edit_action(uid) {
    //send it to php.
}
```

Comment: and catch the value as i did before ?? the same way ??

Comment: @user2175697 Exactly! Just send it using Ajax and access in php using $_GET or $_POST... (depending upon which method you've used to send the request)